# Basic application for Android using SIP not working proper

Tags: android, sip, voip

Has anyone made a small basic application using SIP for android? I have tried using **CSipSimple** app, with SIP account on **antisip.com** and **sip2sip.com** but none of them register properly, and it gives a timeout error.

I also tried those accounts with the SipDemo given with Android, and also in Linphone app. Linphone works fine with a SIP account on Linphone itself, but no other SIP accounts works.

Comment: you can visit https://github.com/ElegantCloud/SipAndroid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to try it out with CSipSimple, Add Account > OSTN

```
Account name: OSTN
Username:<yourusername>
Password:<yourpassword>
Server: ostel.co
```

(Register first @ostel.co)
Or you can download [SipWise CE](http://www.sipwise.com/products/spce/) and setup your own local Sip Service Provider - you will not face errors like timeout (as long as you are not far from your wi-fi coverage)

Comment: I can use linphone on windows 7, connected to SipWise CE